# JSON one to one mapping in Azure Databricks with python

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I have 2 JSON structures, I want to create a map for JSON A to JSON B. For eg. A.employee.name will be mapped to B.employee.fullname. When any object of schema A is given , we can expect an output in form of B.
salary should be mapped to reenumeration and name should be mapped to fullname,
Input:

```
var A = {"employee": { "name":"sam", "salary":56000,"married":true}}
```

Output:

```
var B = { "employee": {"fullname":"sam","reenumeration":56000,"unmarried":true}}
```

I have created RDD of the JSON object, not sure how to map it.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode,map_keys
from pyspark.sql.functions import get_json_object

testJsonData = spark.read.json("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/SrcObj.json",multiLine=True);

def toMapSrcToTarg(rdd):
    key = str(group[0]);
    values = list(group[1]);

    return Row(key,values,e)

testJsonData.rdd.map(toMapSrcToTarg);

for x in rdd.collect():
    print(x)
```

PS: I am fairly new to azure databricks and python.

Comment: Do you only want to rename those fields and get schema B "manually" or you have an input schema and some predefined mapping you need to apply? It's not clear to me. Also, do you have any reason to use RDD?

Comment: @blackbishop My actual goal is to provide an input schema and some predefined mapping which will transform the output based on one to one or one to many mapping. Can we do that without RDD? Please suggest.

Comment: @blackbishop I have posted my attempt in answer , please suggest how I can do better than this.